# Manipulating DOM with (framework-less) javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Ok, I haven't been using JavaScript without JQuery for quite some time now... But, as coding goes, I have to do without it's power for a project where I can't be sure that JQuery is provided.

The thing I'm trying to do would be the following using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDiv').append('<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>');
});
```

Now to the non-jquery thing, this is what I have and I really can't understand why it isn't working:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function load() {
                var s = '<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>'; 
                var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                element.innerHtml += s;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thing is, nothing happens (the function gets called though). Could it be that the DOM isn't ready when load() is called?. I vaguely remember this code working in the firefox 2.x IE7 era ...

What would be the (a) right solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) not `innerHtml`. Notice the upper case `HTML`. Change that and it should work fine! Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wvbsJ/2/).

By using `innerHtml` you are simply creating a new property on the element object and giving it the value of `s`.

Comment: Oh ****, I totally missed that one, thank you! Need. More. coffee. :-)

Comment: No problem :) Always helps to get a few extra pairs of eyes to look over something! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function load() {
                var s = '<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>';
                var element = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                element.innerHTML += s;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `element.innerHTML += s;`.