# How Do i Instert html below a div

Tags: javascript

i am developing a javascript addon that manipulates the layout of a streaming website i was just wondering is it possible i can insert html below a `<div>` instead of replacing the div

```
document.getElementById('selected_div').innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append a div after another div with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936451/append-a-div-after-another-div-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by appending something to `.outerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('selected_div').outerHTML += "YourTextHere";
```

The `+=` makes it that you add to what the current HTML is, instead of replacing it. If you want to insert something at the end of the div, but still inside it, just do the same, but instead, do use `.innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('selected_div').innerHTML += "YourTextHere";
```

Comment: What is? Using `.innerHTML` and `.outerHTML`?

Comment: @NicholasHazel I am inserting outside the `div`, not outside the `html`. At least, I assume OP didn't give his `body` or `html` tags the `id="selected_div"` because that would just be silly.