# Injecting a div into my site with JS (not able to edit the main theme files) is this possible?

Tags: javascript

I have a site over at [https://sofubiki.com](http://sofubiki.com), running on Wiki.js

There's a column down the left hand side that holds the contents, then there's a big space beneath this that'd be perfect for adding some ad banners or other info. Is there any way to insert a section in this column without being able to edit the main site theme (limited knowledge and a confusing process!) Looking around the web it seems that a JS div is a possibility but I'm not too sure!?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This probably will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936451/append-a-div-after-another-div-with-javascript/16936793

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!